# How can I use ForEach-Object output for Select-String directly?

Tags: powershell

I have several single line xml files out of which I want to extract the contents of a particular tag `<LIFNR>`. I managed doing that using the following two lines of power shell:

```
get-content P:\Webservice\21*_*CR_d*.xml | foreach-object { $_ -replace '>', ">`r`n" } > xmls_newline.txt
get-content .\xmls_newline.txt | Select-String -Pattern '.*<\/LIFNR>'
```

However if I want to skip the step of creating an intermediary text file I cannot achieve the same result.

```
$xml = get-content P:\Webservice\21*_*CR_d*.xml | foreach-object { $_ -replace '>', ">`r`n" }
$xml | Select-String -Pattern '.*<\/LIFNR>'
```

or

```
get-content P:\Webservice\21*_*CR_d*.xml | foreach-object { $_ -replace '>', ">`r`n" } | Select-String -Pattern '.*<\/LIFNR>'
```

each just print the result of the string splitting in the foreach-object statement, the Select-String command is ignored.

Can somebody explain to me what is different about the latter two attempts compared to the working solution?

Comment: Why not parse the file as XML?

Comment: A valid concern, but for one thing I don't know how and - more importantly - I want to know the answer to this exact question. This being an XML is of no particular importance, this could be any text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-Content` outputs each line as a separate string. To emulate the same behavior, *split* the string after `>` instead of appending a linebreak:

```
Get-Content P:\Webservice\21*_*CR_d*.xml |ForEach-Object { $_ -split '(?<=>)' } | Select-String -Pattern '.*<\/LIFNR>'
```

The construct `(?<=...)` is a lookbehind assertion - this way, PowerShell will split on a zero-length string immediately after `>`

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works perfectly!
Just for clarification so I really get this: The -replace leaves the XML input still in a single one line string which is then piped to Select-String which matches the first occurence and returns the entire line of that occurence, hence the entire string.
Saving and retrieving from a file "splits" the string because of the newlines and thus Select-String is fed single lines. 


U doing the split is basically doing the same?